# How can you stage all non-deleted files?

Tags: git

I deleted some files that contain tests to temporarily remove those tests from the test runner. I would now like to only stage all files that have been modified, leaving the deleted files unstaged.

I could add modified files one at a time, but it would be nice to do it in one command. Is there a way to do this in one command?

```
> git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   test/file1    # stage this
        deleted:    test/file2    # don't stage this
        deleted:    test/file3    # don't stage this
        modified:   test/file4    # stage this
        modified:   test/file5    # stage this
```

Comment: The `--no-all` aka `--ignore-removal` flag specifies adding modified *and new* files while ignoring removed files, which is not quite the same but might be sufficient. I never use it myself though. For large lists I run `git status --short > /tmp/something` and then modify the output file into the desired commands.

Comment: I'd say it's unclear if it's "not quite the same"; question doesn't specify what to do with untracked files.  I interpreted it to mean that the only "unusual" behavior expected was to ignore deletes...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `--no-all` option (or its longer synonym `--ignore-removal`)

```
git add --no-all .
```

The documentation states that this is meant to support users who are accustomed to older semantics for `add` (basically `--no-all` used to be the default), which IMO is one step short of calling it a deprecated behavior.  I would suggest that you might want to consider workflows that don't require temporary/unwanted modifications to your work tree, because you are still vulnerable to accidentally committing something you don't intend.